# How to get N easily distinguishable colors with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, colormap

I need to make different amounts of line plots with Matplotlib, but I have not been able to find a colormap that makes it easy to distinguish between the line plots.
I have used the brg colormap like this:

```
colors=brg(np.linspace(0,1,num_plots))
```

with

```
for i in range(num_plots):
    ax.step(x,y,c=colors[i])
```

With four plots, this could look like this:

[image]

Notice how hard it is to distinguish the colors of the top and bottom plots, which is especially bad if a legend is used.
I've tried a lot of different colormaps like rainbow and jet, but with this setup, brg seems to give the best result for `num_plots` between 1 and 12.

I did find this [How to get 10 different colors that are easily recognizable](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108733/how-to-get-10-different-colors-that-are-easily-recognizable) and this Wiki page [Help:Distinguishable colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Distinguishable_colors), but I don't know if this can be used in any way..

Is there an easy fix to this, or will I have to make do with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the `tab10` or `tab20` colormaps. See [Colormap reference](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html)

[image]

However, I believe you will always have trouble distinguishing hues when the number of lines becomes large (I would say >5 and certainly >10).
In this case, you should combine hues with other distinguishing features like different markers or linestyles.

```
colors = matplotlib.cm.tab20(range(20))
markers = matplotlib.lines.Line2D.markers.keys()
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,4, figsize=(4*4,4*2))
for nlines,ax0 in zip(np.arange(5,21,5), axs.T):
    ax0[0].set_title('{:d} lines'.format(nlines))
    for n,c,m in zip(range(nlines),colors,markers):
        y = x*np.random.random()+np.random.random()
        ax0[0].plot(x,y)
        ax0[1].plot(x,y, marker=m, markevery=10)
axs[0,0].set_ylabel('only hues', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
axs[1,0].set_ylabel('hues+markers', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, looks good - I didn't know about the `markevery` option - now it's only a problem of the size of the markers, as `s=50` is very different from marker to marker. But thanks anyway :)